# Electron and angular ipcrender

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, electron

I try to call some electron api from angular and respone on it. For test i try to hide block:

electron.ts:

```
import {app,BrowserWindow,BrowserWindowConstructorOptions, ipcMain} from 'electron'
let window:any = null
app.whenReady().then(()=>{
    const options:BrowserWindowConstructorOptions = {
        width:300,
        height:600,
        title:"test",
        show:false,
        webPreferences: {
            nodeIntegration: true,
            contextIsolation : false
        }
    }
    window = new BrowserWindow(options)

    window.loadFile('some path')
    window.webContents.on('did-finish-load',()=>{
        window.show()
        ipcMain.on('test',(value)=>{
           window.webContents.send('test2')
         
        })
    })
})
```

app-component.html:

```
<div *ngIf='__flag'><h1>Test</h1>
    <button (click)='clickFunction()'>Test button</button>
</div>
```

app-component.ts:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { ElectronService, NgxElectronModule } from 'ngx-electron';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-component',
  templateUrl: './app-component.html',
})
export class AppComponentComponent implements OnInit {
  
  __flag:boolean = true

  constructor(private route:Router, private elect:ElectronService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }
  
clickFunction(){
  this.elect.ipcRenderer.send('test')
  this.elect.ipcRenderer.on('test2',()=>{
    this.__flag=false
    console.log(this.__flag);
    
  })
}
}
```

But div removes only if i clicked twice on button. Why it happens? And how can i fix that? I need to hide block then button clicked

Answer (score 1):

You are only setting up the event listener(this.elect.ipcRenderer.on('test2') in your clickFunction after you've sent the message to the main process. Therefore the listener isn't listening yet when the call from the main process arrives. It works on the second click because the listener has been configured in the first click and therefore you get the message.
Move your event listener to the ngOnInit function and it should be fine.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.elect.ipcRenderer.on('test2',()=>{
        this.__flag=false
        console.log(this.__flag);
    }); 
}
  
clickFunction(){
  this.elect.ipcRenderer.send('test');
}
```